# Monitor Mininet-Wifi Link's Delay with RYU controller

Tags: mininet, ryu

I'm a rookie of ryu, I want to modify this app https://github.com/wildan2711/delay_monitor_sdn/blob/master/delay_monitor.py to my structure. What should I do? Here's my structure [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH3LZ.png) If i wnat to get the result of controller to 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.2.1, 192.168.2.2's delay, how can I modify it?